# Uploadify in mozilla

Tags: jquery, uploadify

Hi am using Uploadify plugin(uploadify.v2.1.4.min.js) to upload photos.My issue is in mozilla. When i click on button the dialog box opens, the uploadify works fine but the issue is when i click on other tabs,links on my application when my uploadify dialog box is opened.Here dialog box vanishes when i click background links,tabs on my application when the dialogbox is opened and the page goes to the respective page clicked on link.This happens only in mozilla but in other browsers it works fine(the dialogbox will not allow untill u click cancel) .Can anybody give the solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not very familiar with this plugin, and I'm not sure what you've done with your implementation, here's a possible solution.

You could use a transparent element (probably a `div`) and display it between your page and the dialog, with a height and width to take up the entire window. You can set the `z-index` in CSS for the element and dialog to get them to overlay the page properly. You would show the transparent masking element when the dialog opens and hide it when it closes.

Comment: @abhi did this ever solve your problem? If so, please accept the solution.